# Unable to get my PCE-AC56 working properly, but was only able to get it working and decently stable once

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, drivers, 64bit, pci

I've been trying to get my Asus PCE-AC56 to work with Linux Mint 18.3, which the wireless card has a Broadcom BCM4352 chip on it. I was able to at times, but it would run terrible when playing a game and give me terrible network speed, so I kept trying to find a solution to my speed issue, only for it to be to little to no avail.

I was able to actually get a really good speed out of the card with [*this*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper) (15Mb/s, usual internet speed)! But after I restart, just to be sure that it would work after a simple restart, it stopped working.

I tried to diagnose what was causing the card from not loading, hardware-wise, reported by `ndiswrapper -l`:

- tried reinstalling `bcmwl-kernel-source` via Synaptic Package Manager;
- removing `blacklist bcm43xx`, `blacklist b43`, `blacklist b43legacy` and `blacklist ssb` from `etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`;
- checking the syslog from `/etc/log/syslog` but was too much to look through;
- reinstalling `ndiswrapper`, `ndisgtk`, and the driver for the card, which was `bcmwl6.inf`;

  - the wireless card would've also worked with `bcmwdi.inf`, regardless of which, as I tested, from my Windows 10 drive, before I restarted

All leading me here back to the same spot, with 'Wireless' in Network Manager nowhere to be found and unable to use my wireless network card.

**What am I doing wrong (or did I do wrong) and how can I fix what I could've possibly broke?**

EDIT: just in case, both `iwconfig` and `ip addr` never printed out a `wlan0` nor a `bcmwl6` (the second one which `ndiswrapper -l` outputs)

Answer (score 2):

## Solution:

Worked after installing `broadcom-sta-dkms`, then purging it, installing `bcmwl-kernel-source`, then purging it.
The last few things I did was `sudo apt purge ndis*`, which removed any `ndis`-related packages,
then reinstalled `bcmwl-kernel-source` via Driver Manager (which got the WiFi working again, but I would rather use a Windows driver), reverting it back to not use any driver, then reinstall `ndisgtk` (and required dependencies) as mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper#Installing_packages_With_internet_access_on_the_Ubuntu_computer).

Finally, installing `bcmwl6.inf` via the NDISwrapper user interface and reconnecting to my router!